# Can Robots.txt settings be edited so that google can index the website which is hosted in salesforce?

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, website-integration

Is there anyway to edit the robots.txt settings in salesforce developer edition?? I have purchased a domain through a private vendor and hosted my website through salesforce developer edition, but the problem is google is not able to index any of my website pages as robots.txt blocks it, as a result google cannot crawl the website thus making it unsearchable in google search.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can edit robots.txt. Create a visualforce page and then assign it to the robots.txt field in sites setup.

An example file may look like:

```
<apex:page contentType="text/plain" showHeader="false">
User-agent: msnbot
Disallow: /
</apex:page>
```

However in your question you also mention using a custom domain in a Developer Edition organization. This isn't possible. Custom domains for sites are only supported in EE (Enterprise Edition) and UE (Unlimited Edition) organizations.

Comment: You can also generate a sitemap in a similar method so that pages are correctly indexed by google. We do this for our website which is run on sites.

Answer (score 5):

According to a [discussion](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Force-com-Sites-Site-com/robots-txt-and-force-com-Sites/m-p/96475#M39) on the Developer Force boards, you can upload a custom robots.txt via the Metadata API for force.com sites. This method may work for DE org.